# How to rearrange the data to produce a barplot

Tags: r, loops, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I created a small example here for my big data set with more than 400000 records, I was able to plot the point_plot, here the code:

```
Data1 <- data.frame(State=rep('SC',24),ID=rep(11,24),Month=c(rep(1,times=9),
 rep(2,times=6),rep(3,times=9)),Day=c(rep(1:3,each=3),rep(1:2,each=3),
 rep(1:3,each=3)),Group=rep(1:3,8),Value=rep(10.1:20.9,length.out=24)) 

Data2 <- Data1[rep(1:nrow(Data1),4),]

Data <- data.frame(State=c(rep('SC',48),rep('NC',48)),ID=c(rep(11:14,each=24)),
 Month=Data2$Month,Day=Data2$Day,Group=rep(1:3,32),Value=rep(10:20,length.out=96)) 

states = unique(Data$State)                                           
for(j in 1:length(states)) {
 jpeg(file=paste("Pic", j, ".jpeg", sep=""))
 data <- subset(Data,State==states[j])
 plot(data$Month, data$Value, type="p", xlab="Months", ylab="Value") 
 colors <- rainbow(3)

  for (i in 1:3) {      # add lines 
  group <- subset(data, Group==i) 
  lines(group$Month, group$Value, type="p", col=colors[i])   
 } 

 title(paste(unique(data$State),"Value",sep='  '))       # add a title and subtitle 
 leg.txt <- c("G1","G2","G3")                            # add a legend 
 legend("topleft", legend=leg.txt, fill=colors, bty="o")
 dev.off()
}
```

But now I need to plot the bar_plot with the 3 groups side by side for each month, I tried with the following two, but was not able to get it right:

```
1)ggplot(data, aes(factor(data$Month), data$Value, fill = factor(data$Group))) + 
               geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.5) 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = data$Month)
2) barplot(data$Value,beside=T,names.arg=factor(data$Month))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the argument `stat = "identity"` for `geom_bar`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(as.factor(Month), Value, fill = as.factor(Group))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.5, stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_discrete("Group", labels = c("N", "E", "L"))
```

[image]

Comment: One small thing is: in the legend area, I need to change 1,2,3 to N,E,L, so I tried with: p + scale_colour_manual(values=c("green","red","blue"), breaks=c("N","E","L")), but it doesn't work, any idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=Month, y=Value, fill=as.factor(Group))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", color="black")
```

[image]